# Android LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null on Android 4.1.1

Tags: android

I am working on android application. I am stuck in problem.
`getLastKnownLocation(provider)` returns `null` for Android version 4.1.1, while for other versions it is fine. Provider is enabled and the rest is ok.  I don't know where is the problem.  Here is the code.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.clear();
    System.out.println("Current Location = "+latLng);
```

Answer (score 0):

`locationManager.getLastKnownLocation` will return null if the provider is disabled, and here is the documentation

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but provider is enabled. It also returns previous location for other android versions like 4.2 or etc.

Comment: but getLastKnownLocation does not guarantee to return location, if it is null then you should find the current location

Comment: That is the problem i am trying to solve. i want to get current location,is there any other method that i can use for the same ?

Comment: Now i got the current location on android 4.2.2 but facing the same problem on 4.1.1,ie;null location.

Answer (score 0):

try this its working for me...

```
  mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick()
                        {

                            Location myLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();
                            onLocationChanged(myLocation);
                            return false;
                        }
                });
```